# SSL Link Not Working In IE7

Tags: generics, ssl-certificate

Can anyone tell why visiting the below link might lead IE7 to say they can't load the page?

https://www.stlmag.com/media/St-Louis-Magazine/Store/At-Home-Subscriptions/

I thought it might be an SSL redirect issue, the link before was just http:// ... and then it automatically redirected to https:// but that didn't help.  I'm thinking it's a corporate firewall deal, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything obvious.

Anyone in IE7 having issues with getting that page to show up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could *possibly* be a firewall issue, but it could also be an issue with not having an updated version of root security zones. They may simply need to get their windows updates. As I was unable to reproduce this issue (even with a native IE7) i'm assuming it has little to do with IE7 itself.